# How can I get two threads to read from one inputStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream

I have on input stream coming in that is periodically receiving data. One of my threads (let's call it threadA) reads every message from the stream and makes sure the data is ok, but will through an error otherwise. My other thread (let's call it threadB) needs to read a few specific messages and then process it. As of now I have threadA just store the important messages in a global variable, and threadB read the messages from the global variable.

Is there any way to allow for two threads to read from the same source to avoid this?

edit: the data coming in are responses to commands threadB issued. My issue is that threadB needs the replies from certain commands, which are issued in no particular pattern, but it does not need all the replies.

Comment: It doesn't sound like two threads are necessary. The first is merely a filter. Do the filtering and processing in one thread. Alternatively, have the first thread filter data into a second stream which is read by the second thread.

Comment: The issue is that threadB only needs some replies. So if I have it read every reply then sometimes it will be sitting around wasting time waiting for a reply that it doesn't even need.

Comment: @alex Then only have it wait for a reply when it needs one.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I am a little new to Java. To read in I have a scanner, and do `if(in.hasNextLine()){doSomething(in.nextLine());}`. If I run this code when I need the reply wouldn't it provide me with the oldest message that I have yet to read? So if I send a message without a need for the reply, then send one that needs a reply. Wouldn't I read the reply of the first message first? let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could create a threadsafe inputstream or a wrapper and if the stream supports mark/reset you could also have two streams read the data in parallel. However, you'd have to handle situations where one thread reads faster than the other thus making mark/reset unusable or having to skip data - there's so much involved, I doubt you'll want to bother with all this.

I'd suggest you keep your basic setup but try to get rid of global variables, e.g. by using the obverser pattern, passing references to the shared store to the threads etc.

Comment: The two threads most likely will read at different speeds, as one is a designated reader, and the other needs to read and do other processes at the same time. Unfortunately there is not predictable pattern to the messages coming (see edit). Is there still a way to eliminate global variables?

Comment: @alex as I said create an appropriate thread-safe structure for your message store (e.g. using queues based on type) and pass a reference to that store to your threads (e.g. in the constructor). Then let your reader thread put messages into the store and the processor take them from there.